# Error writing pandas to csv with euro sign delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to write a Pandas data frame to a csv with '€' as a delimiter.

```
data.to_csv(file_path, sep = '€')
```

however, I get the error:

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

How can I overcome this issue?
I must use the euro sign as a delimiter

Comment: € is a special character so it doesnt single character ...use another delimiter like - or tab...just dont use special character

Comment: Unfortunately I must use the euro sign

Comment: Use regular expression foe delimiter then

Comment: how can use regex for the euro sign?

Comment: sep : Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this. Regular expressions are accepted.
This is from documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2):

**Time to switch to python 3.**

This is because by default string is ascii in python 2. ASCII characters are 1 byte (hence their range is 0 to 127). This is not sufficient to represent all characters; in this case '€'. To represent this 3 bytes is needed.

Hence the world switched to unicode. Which has higher range. Luckily python3 uses unicode for all its string.
In python3 `data.to_csv(file_path, sep = '€')` will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an encoding that uses only one byte to encode '€', like iso8859-15 or cp1252:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
sep = u'€'.encode('iso8859-15')
result = df.to_csv(sep=sep)
print result.decode('iso8859-15')

€0€1€2
0€1€2€3
1€4€5€6
```

Note that this won't work in python 3, where `sep` must be a unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Python3.

This code works for me:

```
df = pd.read_csv('', sep='‰', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
```