# pandas read_csv use a unicode character as seperator/delimiter.

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Can we use unicode character seperators in pandas for reading csv?

Gitting this error
TypeError: "delimiter" must be string, not unicode

Comment: Take a look at this post, looks like you may need to switch to python 3 if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35867062/6163621

Comment: you could try reading all file as a string (open.. ) and replace the delimiter with '#$#

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This code works for me in Python3:

```
df = pd.read_csv('', sep='‰', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
```

There was also an interesting answer to a similar issue in Python2 here [Pandas read_csv and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690122/pandas-read-csv-and-utf-16)